# Why is the image blocking the button in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I use Login.js component. So, when I add Image in background the button does not appear.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
     
     <Image source={require('../../assets/LoginScreen.png')} style={styles.img}/>
     <View style={styles.container}>
    
          <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        placeholder="Kullanıcı adınızı giriniz"

        value={text}
       />
       <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
        value={number}
        placeholder="Parolanızı giriniz"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
        <Text>Giriş Yap</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
       
    </SafeAreaView>
```

```
main:{
        flex:1
    },
    container:{
        // flex:1,
        // alignItems:'center',
        // justifyContent:'center'
    },
    
    img:{
      width:'100%',
      // flex:1
    },
   
    input:{
        
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
    },
    button:{
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
      padding: 10,
    }
```

So, what am I missing? I want to make classic Login page. One image in the background and two text input in the middle. One button above text input.

Comment: Hm looks good to me, maybe try giving the button a higher `zIndex` style value than the image could help to enforce the image being rendered underneath the button.

Comment: Is it related to be Stack.Screen component?

Comment: Maybe the ImageBackground component suits the case better.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground